# Targeting an exact text match (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, filter, match, target

I need to target multiple classes by their exact text match. Half of my code appears to work (the text has a purple background when the checkbox is unchecked), but when checking the checkbox to target the text, nothing seems to be happening...

```
if ($("input:checkbox:checked#checkbox-id").length > 0) {
        $('#main-content-panel .entry').filter(function(index) { 
        return $(this).text() == "Text"; }).css
        ('backgroundColor', 'orange'); 
        }

if ($("input:checkbox:not(:checked)#checkbox-id").length > 0) {
        $('#main-content-panel .entry').filter(function(index) { 
        return $(this).text() == "Text"; }).css
        ('backgroundColor', 'purple'); 
        }
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KKfEF/

Comment: You haven't got an event to fire on checkbox change? What do you want to happen?

Comment: With the first block of code I am trying to say, "if the checkbox is checked, change the background color to orange".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should listen to the `change` event:

```
var $elem = $('#main-content-panel .entry').filter(function (index) {
    return $(this).text() == "Text";
});
$('#checkbox-id').change(function () {
    var color = this.checked ? 'orange' : 'purple';
    $elem.css('backgroundColor', color);
}).change();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/drcpY/

Comment: Works great in the Fiddle, but in my code nothing's happening when I check the box... hmm...

Comment: Yes, unfortunately it doesn't help :/ thanks for your suggestion and help, is there anything else that could prevent this?

Comment: No errors that I can see related to this code. I can't figure out why it won't work...

Comment: @Chris No errors that I can see related to this code? Do you mean there is an error? Some errors prevent execution of the whole code.

Comment: Timestamp: 25/01/2013 01:00:30
Error: [Exception... "'JavaScript component does not have a method named: "handleEvent"' when calling method: [nsIDOMEventListener::handleEvent]"  nsresult: "0x80570030 (NS_ERROR_XPC_JSOBJECT_HAS_NO_FUNCTION_NAMED)"  location: "<unknown>"  data: no]

Comment: I will have a look into this tomorrow. Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

you forgot to add an onchange event handler.

```
onchange="run()">
```

Wrap your code in a function too, like so

```
run = function () {
if ($("input:checkbox:checked#checkbox-id").length > 0) {
            $('#main-content-panel .entry').filter(function(index) { 
            return $(this).text() == "Text"; }).css
            ('backgroundColor', 'orange'); 
            }

if ($("input:checkbox:not(:checked)#checkbox-id").length > 0) {
            $('#main-content-panel .entry').filter(function(index) { 
            return $(this).text() == "Text"; }).css
            ('backgroundColor', 'purple'); 
            }
}
run();
```

Comment: you copied the code incorrectly and didnt put the onchange event handler in. http://jsfiddle.net/drcpY/2/

Comment: Ah, thanks for the Fiddle. Your suggestion works well in the Fiddle but again not in my code, not sure why. I'll have to tackle my issue from another angle. Thanks for your time.